# Hadoop: concept of nodes and its working mechanism

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I just began studying hadoop (based on 2.6.0) and still have trouble in getting a big picture of how hadoop is structured physically and logically.

All the references I have found use the term "node" like master/slave nodes and name/data nodes, but I couldn't find clear definitions of such "nodes" from none of them. (maybe I missed the details...)

What I would like to know is, are master/slave "nodes" the terms for physical machines and name/data "nodes" the terms for processes which manage actual data?

My second question is, how such nodes communicate each other? What I know is that they need ssh for communication but no more than that. It would be really helpful if I have a clue how they actually communicate each other to understand its architecture.

ps. Is there any good online reference to study hadoop? For me hadoop website is too unkind for beginners like me and blogs that I found so far are sometimes uninformative. Please share some good resources!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> are master/slave "nodes" the terms for physical machines and name/data
>   "nodes" the terms for processes which manage actual data?

Well, namenode datanode etc are hadoop daemon services that run on a physical machine. So if you have system in your cluster which has the namenode service running then its called a namenode. A single node may run more than one service i.e., it can run a namenode and datanode although in a production setup it is not done since we don't want the machine that is running namenode service to be  overburdened. Since you are using hadoop 2.6 ,you might also want to have a look at the [YARN architecture](http://www.slideshare.net/hortonworks/apache-hadoop-yarn-enabling-nex) to understand how jobs are getting executed

> how such nodes communicate each other? What I know is that they need
>   ssh for communication but no more than that.

Have a look at [this](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hdfs_design.html#The+Communication+Protocols).
Datanode uses [DatanodeProtocol](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-hdfs/2.1.0-beta/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/server/protocol/DatanodeProtocol.java) to communicate with Namenode. This interface provides ability to send heartbeat messages, new datanode registration, block report etc. Client communicates with Datanode using [DataTransferProtocol](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.ning/metrics.serialization-all/2.0.0-pre5/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/protocol/DataTransferProtocol.java). This interface provides ability to read block,write block,copy block etc.

> Is there any good online reference to study hadoop?

Take a look at  [this](http://bradhedlund.com/2011/09/10/understanding-hadoop-clusters-and-the-network/) and [this](https://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/index.html) - might be slightly different from new architecture, but still it is good to read. 
[bigdatauniversity](http://bigdatauniversity.com/wpcourses/) has lot of courses for beginners.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :-) I will take a look at the sources you gave to me and add a comment or post a new question if I still have something hard to understand.